# Interesting Single Variable Calc Question

Tags: calculus

Define the function $h$ by $h(x)=x^2$ if $x$ is rational and $h(x)=0$ if $x$ is irrational. Show that $h$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

My idea was that if we take the limit definition of the derivative, the limit would have to exist and equal the same thing when considering rational and irrational values of $x$. So I took the limit definition of the derivative and evaluated it once assuming irrational values and once assuming rational values and the derivative approached $0$ in both scenarios, implying that $h'(x)=0$ exists. Is there a flaw to this logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is differentiable.  Notice that $$\frac{h(0+x)-h(0)}{x}=\frac{h(x)}{x}=\begin{cases}x&x\in\mathbb Q\\0&x\in\mathbb R\backslash\mathbb Q\end{cases}$$
Therefore, as $x\to 0,\ \frac{h(x)}{x}\to 0\implies h(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$.